# how do I pass an object from a shared data service to an Angular 5 validator directive

Tags: angular

I would like to use a custom validator to validate an input value like this:

```
 <input type="email" name="email" id="email" email="true" appCheckEmail required....
```

where appCheckMail is the custom validator.

The challenge is appCheckMail needs to check the input email against an array of emails...something like this:

```
export class CheckEmailDirective implements Validator {
  constructor(private sharedData: SharedDataService) { }

  validate(control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null {
 return this.sharedData.dealers.includes(email) ? {'emailExist': true} : null;
}
```

The problem is I am not sure how to pass the sharedData.dealers array to the directive..is it even possible? I know I can use @Input in the directive and assign a value to appCheckEmail in the view like this:  appCheckEmail = "test value". All the examples I see uses a string value...I tried assigning a binding value like this   appCheckEmail = {{test.alue}} but that didn't work. So how do I pass a shared data to a directive? Obviously injecting it is not an option.

Comment: I am wondering why are you trying to use directive to validate your input. If it's reactive forms, you can pass the custom validator funtions to formControl

Comment: @RukshanDangalla Probably AngularJS' way of doing validation?

Comment: @HarryNinh have a look at https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl

Comment: where is the array of emails coming from ? from UI form fields or from a service?

Comment: @pixelbits The array of email is coming from a service....basically I am loading an array from a db

Comment: @RukshanDangalla with the reactive forms example I am only allowed to pass a string via the UI...or so it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the array of emails is coming from a service and you're using template-driven forms:

```
<input #tmp type="email" name="email" id="email" email="true" appCheckEmail>
```

AppCheckEmailValidator directive:

```
@Directive({

  selector: '[appCheckEmail][ngModel],[appCheckEmail][formControl]',
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALIDATORS useExisting: forwardRef(() => AppCheckEmailValidator , multi: true }
  ]

})

export class AppCheckEmailValidator implements Validator,
    constructor(private sharedData: SharedDataService) { 
        this._createValidator();
    }
    validate(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors|null {
        return this._validator(c);    
    }
    registerOnValidatorChange(fn: () => void): void { this._onChange = fn; }
    private _createValidator(): void {
        this._validator = MyValidators.appCheckEmail(this.sharedData.dealers);
    }
}
```

Note: NG_VALIDATORS is a hook to add your own validators. Angular will inject NG_VALIDATORS, add your validator to the list of multi-provider validators, and execute them.

**MyValidators:**

```
export class MyValidators {
    public static appCheckEmail(emailsToCheck: string[]): ValidatorFn {
         return (c: AbstractControl) => {
             if (!control.value || control.value === '') {
               return null;  // don't validate empty values to allow optional controls

             }
             if (emailsToCheck.indexOf(c.value)>=0)
                 return {  emailExist: true  };
             return null;
         }
    }
}
```

Here is an [article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/14/custom-validators-in-angular-2.html) explaining the approach.  And here is an [example](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/validators.ts#L200) of the MinlengthValidator from the Angular source.

Please note, this hasn't been tested... But it should work.

Comment: @pixelbits.......since not tested can you explain why you think it will work? I am not familiar with the attr directive! What is OnChanges? how is it introduced?

Comment: I realized your use case is a lot simpler. You don't actually need to pass an argument to through the attribute value (since you get it from the service).